# Pasar un archivo.txt a un array

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy tratando de pasar la información de un archivo .txt, el archivo contiene números separados por una ','. Quiero pasar esta info a un array, pero lo que intentado no me funciona.

```
Impulso1 = open('Impulso1.rtf')

Impulso_1= []
for line in Impulso1:
      line = line.rstrip()
      if line.startswith(','):
            Impulso_1.append(line)

print(Impulso_1)
```

Al momento de imprimir la lista Impulso_1 me retorna vacia, creo que me falta un proceso extra para poder separar la info por ',' y agregarla en la nueva lista.

Comment: Podrías mostrar el formato de los datos del archivo que intentas leer

Comment: si claro <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Impulso1.rtf' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> y adentro contiene información de este tipo '[193,843,0,-345,-1393,.....]', en pocas palabras la info ya esta como un arreglo dentro del archivo .rtf

Comment: Y si usas `data=json.load(open('Impulso1.rtf'))` ? (requiere `import json`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numeros: 11,555,88,44,121,5454

```
Impulso1 = open('Impulso1.rtf')

Impulso_1 = []
for line in Impulso1:
    line = line.rstrip()
    numero = ""
    for x in line:
        if x.find(','):
            numero += str(x)
        else:
            Impulso_1.append(int(numero))
            numero = ""
print(Impulso_1)
```

Salida: **[11, 555, 88, 44, 121]**

Solo te quedaria acomodarlo segun el formato del texto, si lleva [], eliminarlos o si hay un salto de linea y no termina en **,**